# Compare items in all positions of list

Tags: c#

I have the following class:

```
public class Person {
   public String Name { get; set; }
   public Int32 Age { get; set; }
}
```

And I have two lists of person:

```
List<Person> a = service.GetPersons("a");
List<Person> b = service.GetPersons("b");
```

The lists have the same size. Is it possible, using a Lambda expression, to check if for the same position the person is has the same Name and Age in the two lists? I want to check in all positions.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want this answer strictly in the format of using a Lambda expression right?  Or can it be any other solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it with [`SequenceEqual`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342073(v=vs.100).aspx) and a custom comparison, like this:

```
var personCmp = new PersonComparer();
var same = a.SequenceEqual(b, personCmp);
...
class PersonComparer : IEqualityComparer<Person> {
    public bool Equals(Person p1, Person p2) {
        return p1.Name==p2.Name && p1.Age == p2.Age;
    }
    public int GetHashCode(Person p) {
        return p.Name.GetHashCode()*31 + p.Age;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`Zip()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip) to solve this:

```
var equals = a.Zip(b, (xa, xb) => new Tuple<Person, Person>(xa, xb))
              .All(t => 
                       t.Item1.Name == t.Item2.Name &&
                       t.Item1.Age == t.Item2.Age);
```

Note that this will only be correct if the two lists *really* have the same size.

Comment: @S.Akbari thx, added the missing bracket and removed the superfluos.

Comment: @IvanStoev that's correct, but OP stated explicitly that the lists are of same size.

Answer (score 0):

This code is not compiled or tested...

You can look for dupes like this:

```
// With same index in list...

for(int i=0;i<a.Count;i++)
{
    if(a[i].Name == b[i].Name)
    {
        // do something
    }
}


// check each index in list a against every item in list b
List<Person> duplicates = a.Where(person_A => b.Any(person_B => person_A.Name === person_B.Name)).ToList();


// check by index using lambda...
List<Person> duplicates = a.Where(person_A, index => b[index].Name == person_A.Name).ToList();
```